# problem creating conda environment with nodejs>=12.0 and matplotlib

Tags: node.js, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create a conda environment that will enable me to use JupyterLab extensions as well as matplotlib (among other things). When installing JupyterLab extensions in the past, I have been prompted that I require nodejs>=12.0. When I try installing both nodejs and matplotlib in a new environment, I receive a conflict. Any suggestions for how to proceed?

I do the following:

```
conda create -n test python=3.10
conda activate test
conda install jupyterlab
conda install nodejs
conda install matplotlib
```

Installation proceeds without a problem until the final step, at which point I am informed:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               anaconda/linux-64::blas-1.0-mkl None
  ...
  zstd               anaconda/linux-64::zstd-1.5.2-ha4553b6_0 None

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  icu                                       68.1-h2531618_0 --> 58.2-he6710b0_3 None
  nodejs                                 16.13.1-hb931c9a_0 --> 10.13.0-he6710b0_0 None


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Of course, if I allow it to downgrade nodejs, then I won't be able to use Jupyter Lab extensions, which require nodejs>=12.0. Any suggestions for how to proceed?

(Other packages want to downgrade nodejs to 10.3 as well, e.g. `conda install jupyter`, but for clarity, I've focused on matplotlib.)

Comment: I don't know of any useful JupyterLab extension which still require nodejs since JupyterLab 3.0 was released. Most extensions are now distributed as pre-built bundles (installable with `pip install`) which do not require Node.js (in any version) at all. Do you have a specific extension in mind? (Note: JupyterLab 4.0 will have an extension manager installing from PyPI to complete the transition).

Comment: Another general comment is that you appear to be using the default conda channel. conda-forge may be a better idea if you want to get recent versions of stuff without running into conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue, and I got around it by not installing node via conda.  I think node just needs to be on your path so you can install with https://nodejs.org/en/download/ or if you need to support multiple node versions you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).